# How to mix two orderby-parameters into one ordered result

Tags: wp-query, sort

I'm trying to figure out how to get an alphabetically ordered list of posts using two different orderby parameters.

Im filtering the archive query something like this:

```
function change_sort_order_on_archive() {
  if ( is_archive() AND $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'my_extra_title_field' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value title' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_sort_order_on_archive');
```

But the results show posts sorted by meta_field first (A-Z) then shows the rest of the posts (those that don't have the meta field) sorted by title (A-Z). IE two distinct sorted groups of posts.

What i want is one single sorted group of posts (A-Z) that uses the meta field if it exists and otherwise uses the title field to place it in order.

Is it possible or do i have to re-sort my query before printing it to the actual page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax below :

```
$query->set('orderby', array('title' => 'ASC', 'meta_value' => 'ASC'));
// $query->set('order', 'ASC' ); // not needed any more
```

Comment: Hmm, this produces one sorted group but that is because all posts have a title field, but only some have the meta field. So with this none of the posts are sorted according to the meta field.